# What is meant with 'Fourier mode'?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am wondering what the notion *Fourier mode* means.

Here is what I think it means:

Suppose, we have a function $u=u(x,t)$ which we can express as Fourier integral with respect to $x$:
$$
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ikx}\tilde{u}(k,t)\, dk,
$$
where $\tilde{u}(k,t)$ is the Fourier transform. Now, for $\tilde{u}(k,t)$ we make the product ansatz
$$
\tilde{u}(k,t)=e^{-i\omega t}\tilde{u}(k).
$$ 
That is, we are trying to write $u(x,t)$ as
$$
u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{i(kx-\omega t)}\tilde{u}(k)\, dk.
$$

Now, as far as I am informed, the functions
$$
e^{i(kx-\omega t)}
$$
are called *Fourier modes*.

So, Fourier modes are complex travelling waves?

How can they be vizualized?

Comment: I'm not allowed to comment yet, so I'll write this short comment as an answer. Here's a [link from the physics section](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/276763/what-is-meant-by-the-term-fourier-mode).